# Transform dataframes to triple store

Tags: python, pandas

I have a bunch of dataframes, all indexed by `timestamp(datetime)`.
Each has a couple of columns, usually with numeric values.

```
timestamp tag celc
2018-03-15 20:05:01.080 1 52
2018-03-15 20:05:23.630 1 52
2018-03-15 20:12:16.990 1 53


timestamp   bpm
2018-03-15 20:05:01 50.00
2018-03-15 20:21:41 74.00
2018-03-15 20:38:21 65.33
```

What I am looking to do is transform them to the following format

```
timestamp label value
2018-03-15 20:05:01.000 bpm 50.00
2018-03-15 20:05:01.080 tag 1
2018-03-15 20:05:01.080 celc 52
2018-03-15 20:05:23.630 tag 1
2018-03-15 20:05:23.630 celc 52
2018-03-15 20:12:16.990 tag 1
2018-03-15 20:12:16.990 celc 53
2018-03-15 20:21:41.000 bpm 74.00
2018-03-15 20:38:21.000 bpm 65.33
```

I am currently using `.stack()` on the combined tables:

```
pd.concat(dataframes, axis=1).sort_index().stack()
```

This produces the expected result.

> I was wondering whether this is the "right", most efficient approach,
>   or whether I should be doing this differently.

The concatenated table is required for when outputting a different format, if that function can be improved I'd like to know as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DataFrame.melt` to unpivot your dataframes first, and concatnate your dataframes

### Data preparation

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

raw_data = ('''timestamp,tag,celc
2018-03-15 20:05:01.080,1,52
2018-03-15 20:05:23.630,1,52
2018-03-15 20:12:16.990,1,53''',
'''timestamp,bpm
2018-03-15 20:05:01,50.00
2018-03-15 20:21:41,74.00
2018-03-15 20:38:21,65.33''')

dataframes = [
    pd.read_csv(StringIO(x)).assign(timestamp = lambda df:pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)) 
    for x in raw_data
]
```

### Concatenating dataframes

```
pd.concat([df.melt('timestamp') for df in dataframes]).set_index('timestamp').sort_index()
```

### Result

```
                        variable  value
timestamp                              
2018-03-15 20:05:01.000      bpm  50.00
2018-03-15 20:05:01.080      tag   1.00
2018-03-15 20:05:01.080     celc  52.00
2018-03-15 20:05:23.630      tag   1.00
2018-03-15 20:05:23.630     celc  52.00
2018-03-15 20:12:16.990      tag   1.00
2018-03-15 20:12:16.990     celc  53.00
2018-03-15 20:21:41.000      bpm  74.00
2018-03-15 20:38:21.000      bpm  65.33
```

### DataFrames before concatenate

```
dataframes[0].melt('timestamp')
Out: 
                timestamp variable  value
0 2018-03-15 20:05:01.080      tag      1
1 2018-03-15 20:05:23.630      tag      1
2 2018-03-15 20:12:16.990      tag      1
3 2018-03-15 20:05:01.080     celc     52
4 2018-03-15 20:05:23.630     celc     52
5 2018-03-15 20:12:16.990     celc     53

dataframes[1].melt('timestamp')
Out: 
            timestamp variable  value
0 2018-03-15 20:05:01      bpm  50.00
1 2018-03-15 20:21:41      bpm  74.00
2 2018-03-15 20:38:21      bpm  65.33
```

Comment: Great solution!  +1

Comment: Thank you, was not aware of `.melt`. Although the end result seems same as `.stack`, is there a difference ?

Comment: The results are same. I think your approach is good. I used `.melt` because your code creates a relatively large dataframe(timestamp * label) in the intermediate process(`pd.concat(dataframes, axis=1)`).